# How to select the particular repository in bamboo during build?

Tags: bamboo

I am new to use the bamboo server. In the application, i have multiple branches, during the build time, it is possible to normal user to select the particular branch to build other than default repository.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plan branches to build for specific or all branches. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Using+plan+branches for more details.